# Dell WIfi Not working after 14.04 install

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dell, broadcom

Below is wireless related info extracted from other forum advice. Looks like a kernel issue but I'm clueless how to solve. Thanks for any advice.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux john-Vostro-1400 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0227]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05a9:2640 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV2640 Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #####

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search ph.cox.net

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            tg3
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.105
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

##### iwlist channel #####

##### lsmod #####

ssb                    51854  1 
wl                   3999690  1 
lib80211               14040  1 wl
cfg80211              409394  1 wl

##### modinfo #####

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     3DE188310F77C566C2E8CB3
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004350sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000432Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004329sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004328sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004325sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004324sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000A8D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004322sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004321sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004320sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004319sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014A4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004318sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004315sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004312sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004311sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004307sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004306sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004301sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        <MAC address removed>:96:DC:92:B0:1D:75:9D:3E:85:62:EA:32:A1:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     FF25FE784DC6BDFF69DAFCB
alias:          pci:v*d*sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
depends:        cfg80211,lib80211
vermagic:       3.13.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

##### modules #####

lp

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x14e4:0x1713 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #####

[   16.289874] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   16.302998] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   16.384641] wl driver 6.30.223.141 (r415941) failed with code 21
[   16.384690] Modules linked in: snd_pcm dell_wmi videodev wl(POF+) gpio_ich sparse_keymap snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi nouveau(+) snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq r852 sm_common mxm_wmi snd_seq_device nand ttm snd_timer nand_ecc drm_kms_helper dell_laptop nand_bch lib80211 bch dcdbas drm snd r592 nand_ids soundcore psmouse mtd i2c_algo_bit cfg80211 memstick coretemp serio_raw lpc_ich wmi mac_hid video parport_pc ppdev lp parport firewire_ohci tg3 firewire_core ahci ptp libahci sdhci_pci crc_itu_t sdhci pps_core
[   16.384855] EIP is at wdev_priv.part.9+0x3/0x5 [wl]
[   16.384986]  [<fc5589d7>] wl_cfg80211_detach+0xf7/0x100 [wl]
[   16.385042]  [<fc5513c3>] wl_free_if.isra.12+0x23/0xa0 [wl]
[   16.385097]  [<fc551a68>] wl_free+0x78/0x260 [wl]
[   16.385174]  [<fc551f5e>] wl_pci_probe+0x30e/0x630 [wl]
[   16.385340]  [<f84e2017>] wl_module_init+0x17/0x1000 [wl]
[   16.385504] EIP: [<fc558fb6>] wdev_priv.part.9+0x3/0x5 [wl] SS:ESP 0068:f2cadbbc

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

The Broadcom proprietary driver is incorrect for your device. Please hook up the ethernet, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: `linux-firmware-nonfree` is obsolete. Use `firmware-b43-installer` instead.